# How can I use getLine or getChar in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to get from my console a `string` or just a `char` and store into a variable.

I tried to use:

```
> let x = getChar
> x
> c -- for getting a char.
```

But nothing is stored (same for getLine) how can I do?

Comment: Not too far into this tutorial they read in a character: https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/io.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from console, maybe is not very useful. However you should use `<-` construct.

For example (without `"` is good too) :

```
>myString <- getLine
>"Hello world"
```

or

```
>myChar <- getChar
>c
```

For more I suggest to read [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output)

Answer (score 6):

The type of `getChar` is `IO Char`. It is not a function that returns a `Char`; it is an IO action that, when executed, returns a `Char`. (While subtle, this distinction is crucial to understanding how Haskell performs IO with pure functions.)

The line

```
let x = getChar
```

just binds the name `x` to the same IO action (which you can see by subsequently typing `:t x` in GHCi). Typing `x` then executes that action; GHCI waits for you to type a character, then it immediately returns that character.

To use `getChar` in a program, you need to use it within an IO monad, with something like

```
main = do ch <- getChar
          print ch
```

or

```
main = getChar >>= print
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it's very accurate, however I asked for use it directly from the console.

Comment: @user4929787 (I think you're referring to using it from inside `ghci`... if I assumed incorrectly, please let me know!) Try `ch <- getChar` rather than `let ch = getChar`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample

```
main = do
    x <- getLine
    putStrLn $ "Here is the string you typed in: " ++ x
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind it to a variable using **<-**, the result of an action is being bound:

```
*Main> variable <- getLine 
 hello      
*Main> putStrLn variable 
 hello
*Main> anotherChar <- getChar
a*Main> 
*Main> putChar anotherChar 
a*Main>
```

Function **getLine** has type IO String and **getChar** has type IO Char.