# What is the easiest way to query some input values in Haskell

Tags: haskell

What is the easiest way to get some values (yes/no, numbers) into a Haskell program. The values should be bound to some variables and other questions should be asked based on previous inputs.

I am trying to solve a little problem for which I think Haskell is best suited. Especially for extending the functionality afterwards. An addition I am also trying to learn this language (I am new to Haskell but have some experience with Prolog, so have some idea about functional programming).

I was checking all he stuff relatd to GUI development, but this is actually an overkill to what I need. The input should be in response to some questions which are dependent on the state of the execution.

I hope this is clear enough.

EDIT:

I would like to have some "po-ups" like these. Not all at once, but just as a pop-up when needed.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use getLine or getChar in haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37144229/how-can-i-use-getline-or-getchar-in-haskell)

Comment: `main = do x <- readLn ; print (x+100)`

Comment: You could define a free monad to model the interaction... https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-free-1.0.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Free.html

Comment: You state that a GUI is overkill for your purposes; but you've posted images of a GUI. To clarify, do you want a GUI or do you want a command line program? To clarify further, is this question about creating an abstraction to model questions/answers, or about how one creates a GUI popup with a textbox/how one reads input from the user on the command line?

Comment: @user2407038 To answer your second question first: its the second: GUI pop-ups. A complete GUI would go into the FRP direction. I dont need/want to have a predefined GUI with reactions to clicks or inputs. I seek for a improved readLn in a question/answer cycles. So somewhat: "What are you? hungry / dursty", "What would you like to dink? water/non-alk/alk", etc. So after a start some questions are asked and based on the inputs conclusions are drawn and new questions arise. Most of the questions allow just a yes/no, a number, or some predefined options as responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels a little bit like your assumption is that Haskell is like Javascript here.

That is, it's very simple in Javascript to get a "popup" to display in a browser such as Chrome by using `prompt("Are you hungry or thirsty?")`, but that's only because the prompt function is built on top of the `window` object which the browser provides to allow developers to hook into the windowing stack of the operating system that the browser is built in.

Haskell, by default, provides far less functionality "for free". That is, if you want to display a pop up, you'll have to use some library that allows you to display some pop-up.

This is a much bigger question than it possibly seems. It's very similar to the same question in any other batch-style programming language. How would you do this in Java, or in Ruby? Well, you need to find a library that supports it.

One such library for many languages and that is cross platform across operating systems is wxWidgets. It's built in C++, but there are bindings/libraries for Haskell and many other languages. The Haskell library is called wxhaskell: https://wiki.haskell.org/WxHaskell

Good luck, and don't expect it to be an easy path necessarily.

If you have interest in learning Haskell basics, feel free to take a look at this tutorial I helped author: http://happylearnhaskelltutorial.com

Comment: thank you for your clarification. Your solution is what I have found so far as well, apart from some others like  Gtk2Hs, Haskell/GUI or Threepenny-gui, Autoforms. Glade will help also with designing GUIs and doing RFP's. But all of them put some unnecessary overhead to what I am looking for. It seems that WxHaskell is actuallythat what comes closes - in sense of what I try to achieve and required effort.